# Why for-loop factorial function faster than recursive one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have written two functions to calculate combinations. The first one uses a for loop, the other one uses a recursive factorial function. Why is the first faster than the second?

```
def combinations(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    # Collection >= Selection
    if n < k:
        raise ValueError(
            "The size of the collection we are selecting items from must be "
            "larger than the size of the selection."
        )
    # Sizes > 0
    if n < 0 or k < 0:
        raise ValueError(
            "Cannot work with negative integers."
        )
    # Compute with standard python only
    numerator = 1
    for i in range(n + 1 - k, n+1):
        numerator *= i
    denominator = 1
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        denominator *= i
    return int(numerator / denominator)
```

The second function needs a factorial function defined as:

```
def factorial(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError(
            "Cannot calculate factorial of a negative number."
        )
    # Recursive function up to n = 0
    return n * factorial(n - 1) if n - 1 >= 0 else 1
```

And it is defined as:

```
def combinations2(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    # Collection >= Selection
    if n < k:
        raise ValueError(
            "The size of the collection we are selecting items from must be "
            "larger than the size of the selection."
        )
    return int(factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k)))
```

When I run the following test on IPython console, it is clear which one is faster

```
%timeit combinations(1000, 50)
16.2 µs ± 1.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and

```
%timeit combinations2(1000, 50)
1.6 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**NEW VERSION OF COMBINATIONS2**

Okay following the comments, I agree combinations2 is doing many more operations. So I rewrote both factorial and combinations function, here are their versions:

```
def factorial(n: int, lower: int=-1) -> int:
    # n > 0
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError(
            "Cannot calculate factorial of a negative number."
        )
    # Recursive function up to n = 0 or up to lower bound
    if n - 1 >= 0 and n - 1 >= lower:
        return n * factorial(n - 1, lower)
    return 1
```

which now can have a lower bound. Notice that in general factorial(a, b) = factorial(a) / factorial(b). Also, here is the new version of the combinations2 function:

```
def combinations2(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    if n < k:
        raise ValueError(
            "The size of the collection we are selecting items from must be "
            "larger than the size of the selection."
        )
    return int(factorial(n, n - k) / factorial(k))
```

But again, this is their comparison:

```
%timeit combinations(100, 50)
10.5 µs ± 1.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit combinations2(100, 50)
56.1 µs ± 5.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Short version: recursion is expensive.

Comment: Recursion in python is not fast.  Recursion is only fast in (some) other languages because the compiler optimizes away the recursive part of tail-recursion, basically turning it into a loop.

Comment: Try implementing factorial in a different way: instead of `return n * factorial(n - 1)...` define a helper function, which calculates all in their arguments, i.e. `def factorial_help(n: int, acc: int) -> int: return factorial_help(n-1, n*acc) if n-1 > 0 else acc` and rewrite factorial to `... return factorial_help(n, 1)`. Is it still much slower?

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle afaik Python doesn't have tail call optimization

Comment: @dashiell good to know. I would have expected that this way would be faster than the "normal" recursive way, but in this case I think it won't be.

Answer (score 4):

Just count the number of operations:

In `combinations` you are making `(n+1) - (n+1-k)` multiplications for numerator, and `(k+1) - 1` multiplications for denominator.

Total: `2k` multiplications

In `cominations2` you are making `n + k + (n-k)` multiplications, i.e. `2n` multiplications.

And you are making also `2n` function calls for recursion.

With `k=50` and `n=1000`, no wonder why the first solution is faster.